# dynamic filename for raw destination occurs error in ssis

Tags: ssis

Am using few variables to load csv file value into raw destination, and same variables from raw source to oledb destination.

**variables List**

```
 1. CurrentFileName--> FX Accrued Income_20120111_161019.CSV     
2. FilenamePrefix--> it has expression ( ((DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("yyyy", (DT_DATE) @[User::AsOfDate] ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mm", (DT_DATE)@[User::AsOfDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("dd", (DT_DATE)@[User::AsOfDate]) ,2))  )    
3. AsOfDate--> 01/20/2012    
4. Sample Output --> C:\satish\New Folder\     
5. stagingouputpath-->  it has expression ((RIGHT( @[User::sampleoutput] ,1) == "\\" ? @[User::sampleoutput] : @[User::sampleoutput] + "\\")  + SUBSTRING( @[User::CurrentFileName] ,1, FINDSTRING( @[User::CurrentFileName],".", 1) ) + "RAW"    )
```

Now in raw destination ---> i have given access mode has from varibale and  variable name as stagingoutputpath

```
<b> raw destination   
acess mode--> from variable  
filename--> stagingouputpath  
write option--> create always </b>
```

and next level i need to use this ouput destination as input variable for raw source and load it into sql destination..

```
destinaton table contains fields like  
report_dir, reportpatternname, processtype,

now i need to insert this raw source file name to reportpatternnname   
example   
reportdir--C:\satish\New Folder  
reportname--FX Accrued Income
```

in destination table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error SSIS is reporting but you did not state in your questions, is that step 2 is failing because it's an invalid raw file/does not exist. This makes sense because the file does not exist and won't until you run the package. I had assumed since your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923064/fetching-data-from-multiple-file-and-loading-it-into-raw-file-destinationraw-fi) had a requirement for using raw files you were familiar with them.

- http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/

Run your Initialize raw file step and then the next data flow should work. You'll probably want to set delay validation to true.

Comment: The delay validation part of this was incredibly helpful, thank you.