# Dynamic Staging in SSIS using C#

Tags: c#, ssis

Can any one please help me with dynamic staging? I mean, I'm getting files from different locations with the same headers, but the order of the headers in each file is different. I need to load all of the files into a table that I've already created, and I need to map the headers in each file to the fields in the table.

file1.txt

```
Date    FirstName   LastName    Pincode State
10/24/2023  Ramya   Kumari  560001  Karnataka
10/24/2023  Sheela  Kumari  110001  Delhi
```

file2.txt

```
Date    LastName    Pincode FirstName   State
10/24/2023  Kumar   110001  Sheela  Delhi
10/24/2023  Kumar   403001  Leela   Goa
```

file3.txt

```
Date    State   LastName    Pincode FirstName
10/24/2023  Karnataka   Kumar   560001  Ramya   
10/24/2023  Goa Kumar   403001  Leela
```

need help to load all the files into one table

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 DFT Task to achieve your goal:

[image: DFT TASKS]

Each DFT Task should be like this(Send the records to a staging table):
Text01, Text02, Text03

[image: ERDR]

Then Another DFT Task (This time Get data by query from Staging OLEDB Tables)

[image: DFER]

Lastly, run the package and send them to a common OLEDB destination table.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have just given an example for a 3 txt file, but I will receive almost 300 to 500 files every day from different markets with headers in different orders. So I need to read the header, and then I need to map the data into the table that has already been created.

Comment: @Hari you're welcome. I tried a dynamic package to test it which contains for each loop with file enumerator(I put FilePath in a variable and It works no matter how many files a folder contain ), execute sql task(truncate and reload a staging table each time package is run), and DFT Task to load destination table. Order of columns seems to be the problem. As soon as I solve it, I will share my detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck, this is a dynamic case that SSIS can handle. Rather than treat them as "regular" flat files, you can use the JET engine to query them. I covered it a bit on these answers

- [fetching data from multiple file and loading it into raw file destination(raw file should be dynamic) in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923064/fetching-data-from-multiple-file-and-loading-it-into-raw-file-destinationraw-fi/8929658#8929658)
- [SSIS Task for inconsistent column count import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168548/ssis-task-for-inconsistent-column-count-import/8173162#8173162)
- [SSIS FlatFile Access via Jet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626971/ssis-flatfile-access-via-jet/7628389#7628389)